# How to create a static function TLB file for VBA like NI Example?

Tags: c#, tlb

I have a c# library project and try to output a TLB file for VBA.
The TLB file can be used in VBA, but the user needs to create an object instance and use obj.xxx( ) to call a function due to the COM not support static function.
But in the VBA example (NI' example), 
[NI VBA Example](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Program-Drafts/Using-DAQmx-with-Microsoft-Excel-Visual-Basic-for-Applications/ta-p/3518041?profile.language=zh-TW) users don't need to declare the functions and don't need to create an object. How to create a TLB like this?

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab > Register for COM Interop checkbox.  VS must run elevated so it can register the type library and assembly.  Or regasm.exe with the /tlb option, required on the target machine.  Or tlbexp.exe if you only want to generate the type library, but it must be registered to appear in the VBA project dialog.

Comment: Hi Passant~
I can generate the tlb file and can use in VBA. But in the VBA project, I need to new object. If I modify the C# library to static, in the VBA project will not found the function. My question is how to write library or a tlb file, like the example that user need not to new object in VBA project~thanks

Comment: COM does not support static methods. A type library attribute exists to make a coclass look static ([appobject]) but that is not supported by .NET.

Comment: Passant Thanks very much. so what language or what environment can I use to make a type library with coclass look static function? C++?